# install crypt blowfish on xampp on windows

Tags: php, windows, xampp, pear, blowfish

I have a module for a zencart which requires Blowfish Encryption on my server. At the moment I'm just testing on my localhost which is xampp on a windows machine.

Ive googled and looked on stackoverflow but can't find any instructions (at least that I understand) on how to do it.

Is it even possible?

thanks :)

Comment: If it comes down to it, you can always dig through the sources to see how it goes about calling the encryption routine.  That'll probably point you more in the right direction.  I know that Blowfish is one of the options for `crypt()` but I couldn't tell you if that's what they're using.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you use the latest XAMPP, mcrypt is installed by default. According to the PHP website:

> PHP 5.3 Windows binaries uses the static version of the MCrypt
>   library, no DLL are needed.

If you use PHP 5.2.x:

1. Download the Win32 binaries from http://windows.php.net/download/. Ensure which PHP version you have, as you can see there are different ones.
2. Copy `php_mcrypt.dll` to PHP's `ext` directory, and `libmcrypt.dll` to Apache's `bin` directory.
3. Add the following line to the extensions section in `php.ini`: `extension=php_mcrypt.dll`.
4. Finally, restart Apache.

It should work okay. :)

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the answer. I did what you said (hpoefully I was downloading the right thing - my php is 5.2.8 and I downloaded the thread safe version at the bottom of this page http://windows.php.net/download/#php-5.2-ts-VC6-x86 ) But when I restarted apache it didn't make any difference.