# PHP Laravel Framework

Tags: php, laravel-4

I want to route in my project as a starting I wrote this block code in route.php:

```
(line number 8) Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showWelcome');
```

my HomeController.php file is:

```
  <?php

class HomeController extends BaseController {

    public function showWelcome()
    {
        return View::make('hello');
    }

}
```

but I'm getting this type of error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Route' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laravel-master/app/routes.php on line 8
```

Comment: Are you sure you installed the framework correctly ? (using Composer)

Comment: I tried to install but I got an error(Mcrypt PHP extension required.
Script php artisan optimize handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error) when I was installing composer

Comment: Enable your MCrypt extension and try running Composer again.

Comment: How can I enable it I really dont know :(

Comment: I check my phpinfo() in localhost but mcrypt is enable but still not working :(

Comment: looks like xampp has mcrypt installed by default, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8346711/install-crypt-blowfish-on-xampp-on-windows . this is why i dont program on windows, its much harder to get certain things to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can install mcrypt by running

```
pecl install mcrypt
```

Then check file in `/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d` to see if mcrypt is enabled. Depends on your environment though. Check xamp docs to see how to enable it.